# remove image if condition jquery

Tags: jquery, load

I load in a div with class name **".preview"** image's gallery like this:

```
<img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/120226120954-mandela-paper-t1-main.jpg" alt="120226120954-mandela-paper-t1-main">
<img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/120226120954-mandela-paper-t1-main.jpg" alt="120226120954-mandela-paper-t1-main">
<img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/icons/video_icon.gif" alt="Video_icon">
.
.
.
```

I have this function for remove img if exist a condition:

```
 $('.preview').load(function(e){
   img = $(this).find('img');
  if((img.height() < 50) || (img.width() < 50)){
   img.remove();
  }
 });
```

**My problem is that every images are removed**

I just want to remove from **".preview"** the images which have a **width** or **height** less than **50px.**

#### Edited

I get in every images the value **"0"** for height in alert for this code, so delete every the images. But the images have not this value.

```
$('form#get_url_image').bind('ajax:success', function() {

$('.preview img').load(function() {
  var $img = $(this);
   alert ($img.height());
   if ($img.height() < 50 || $img.width() < 50) {
       $img.remove();
   }  
});
});
```

I get the images with each block:

```
<div class="preview">
 <% @images_urls.each do |image_url| %>
  <%=  image_tag "#{image_url}" %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to loop through the individual `<img>` elements.

Given your HTML and code, I think that you want to check the dimensions of the images after they have loaded. To do so, use:

```
$('.preview img').load(function() {
   var $img = $(this);
   if ($img.height() < 50 || $img.width() < 50) {
       $img.remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, This remove every my images :(

Comment: @hyperrjas Then every image has a width *or* height of your test page is smaller than 50px. The demo based on your question works fine (shows 2, hides the last image): http://jsfiddle.net/8D48u/

Comment: Thank you Rob W, I have edited my problem more specific with jquery ujs.

Comment: @hyperrjas I cannot reproduce your problem. Which browser are you using to perform tests? Can you paste an example of the generated HTML at http://pastebin.com/ (including references to the (dummy) images)?

Comment: Thank you Rob W, I have write my problem, more specifically in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455368/block-each-rails-3-1-and-jquery if you can help me :D

Comment: I have fixed the problem, the problem was callback fancybox `onComplete` :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So the load event handler will be executed whenever a picture was loaded?

`$(this).find('img')` will always select **all** images inside `.preview` and  therefore `img.remove();` will remove **all** images.

I think you just want to get a reference to the currently loaded one, which you can get with [`event.target` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
$('.preview').load(function(e){
   var img = $(e.target);
   if((img.height() < 50) || (img.width() < 50)){
     img.remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this does not remove any images :(

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<html>
<body>
    <a>Click</a>
    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://placebox.es/200/200/rgb250,45,45/">
        <img src="http://placebox.es/200/200/rgb250,45,45/">
        <img src="http://placebox.es/20/200/rgb250,45,45/">
        <img src="http://placebox.es/200/20/rgb250,45,45/">
        <img src="http://placebox.es/48/48/rgb250,45,45/">
    </div>

    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('a').on('click',function(){
            $('img').each(function(){
                var img= $(this);
                if (img.load()) {
                    if((img.height() < 50) || (img.width() < 50)){
                       img.remove()
                    }
                }
            })  
        })
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have write my problem, more specifically in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455368/block-each-rails-3-1-and-jquery