# block each rails 3.1 and jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I get with Mechanize a array with every images from a web page with this code:

```
url = http://www.cnn.com
page = Mechanize.new.get(url)
@images_urls = page.images.map{|img| img.url.to_s }.compact
```

and I get in my view this images with a block:

```
<div class="preview">
<% @images_urls.each do |image_url| %>
 <%=  image_tag "#{image_url}" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

This array generate urls like e.g.:

```
<img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/120226120954-mandela-paper-t1-main.jpg" alt="120226120954-mandela-paper-t1-main">
<img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/120226120954-mandela-paper-t1-main.jpg" alt="120226120954-mandela-paper-t1-main">
<img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/icons/video_icon.gif" alt="Video_icon">
.
.
.
```

I need a code for remove images less 50px in height and width, then I get

```
$('.preview img').load(function() {
   var $img = $(this);
   alert ($img.width());
   if ($img.height() < 50 || $img.width() < 50) {
       $img.remove();
   }  
});
```

I get in **alert ($img.width());** the value **0** for every images...So remove every images for this condition.

**The images have values ​​greater than zero 0!!**

**Why?**

### Edited Problem Fixed

The problem is that I'm using Fancybox and the code goes after Fancybox callback

**onComplete**

Thank you Rob W

Comment: Which browser are you using to observe this effect? Can you create a demo to show this problem?

Comment: Doesn't look like the images have width and height attributes and I don't *think* you can just ask javascript to calculate width, given an img. So maybe it's just populating with 0 as the default no-value value?

Comment: I'm using mozilla, chrome and opera in every browsers I have this problems. I don't know how show a demo with ruby on rails code. :O. it is very strange.

Comment: Thank you @theWillCole but the code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/8D48u/

Comment: If you think that the Q&A serves use to future visitors, can you remove the answer from the question, and post it as a separate answer? After 48 hours, you can accept it. To make sure that your question can be found via (Google) search, include the relevant tags, and perhaps change the title to something like "Cannot read the width or height of an image in Fancybox". **However**. I think that your question is too incomplete to be useful in the future, so I recommend to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet for determine if the image was loaded, [Here](https://gist.github.com/797120/7176db676f1e0e20d7c23933f9fc655c2f120c58) ..

Comment: Can you write a example with the data from this question? Thank you!

Comment: I make a simple demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zpGdQ/), also I recommend you to see this [plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) ..